# Error upon jar execution - unable to allocate file descriptor table

Tags: java, linux

Upon trying to use a jar on the local linux machine, I am getting the following error: 
library initialization failed - unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memory

The machine has 32G RAM

I can provide additional information, if needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can try increasing the JVM heap memory size using -Xmx  flag when invoking jvm. please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/3981536

Comment: I've already tried doing this, unfortunately, it does not help.

Comment: try inspecting the application using jVisualVM. you get a better understanding of how the memory is growing. also you can look at GC activity using a plugin called VisualGC, that will give good understanding of how various memory area in JVM is behaving

Comment: I just had the same error. You can try enabling memory overcommiting, by setting `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` to 1. That worked for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In recent versions of Linux default limit for the number of open files has been increased significantly. Java 8 does the wrong thing of trying to allocate memory upfront for this number of file descriptors (see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8150460). Previously this worked, when the default limit was much lower, but now it tries to allocate too much and fails. Workaround for this is to set a lower limit of number of open files (or use newer java):

```
$ mvn
library initialization failed - unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memoryAborted
$ ulimit -n 10000
$ mvn
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
```

Comment: worked for me, struggled with that for hours....
simply do smth like `echo "ulimit -n 10000 >> /root/.bashrc"`

Answer (score 1):

Had this happen to me on some Java applications and curiously all electron-based apps (such as Spotify) after upgrading my Manjaro Linux about a week ago (today is November 19, 2019).

What fixed it was this command (as root, sudo didn't do it:

```
echo >/etc/security/limits.d/systemd.conf "* hard nofile 1048576"
```

Then **reboot**

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other fixes I found online worked for me, however I noticed that the [bug responsible for this defect](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8150460) is in Java 9, and has been resolved since.

I'm on ArchLinux so I notice that when I tried to start the `elasticsearch.service` in  `journalctl -xe` it showed that for some reason JRE8 was running it, and indeed `archlinux-java status` showed that Java 8 was the default. Setting to Java 11 fixed the problem for me:

```
 # archlinux-java set java-11-openjdk
```